# Dúvida com troca de componente na migração do eclipse para android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho um aplicativo que foi migrado do eclipse, ele utiliza um componente:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/, mais ele gera erro na abertura da aplicação, desta forma eu precisei comentar o código que se encontra a abaixo para que fosse possível compilar o projeto, preciso fazer a substituição deste componente para que as opções do menu seja visualizada , basicamente ele monta o menu da aplicação, são apenas 3 telas do aap:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
 O código comentado foi este:
//alterado
//ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//actionBar.setTitle(" Sistema ");
//getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(" TESTE");
//getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1985CB")));
```

```html
Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/appcompat-v7-22.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/appcompat-v7-22.2.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/appcompat-v7-22.2.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/appcompat-v7-22.2.1.jar
Required by:
    :SafariProjetoPanda:unspecified

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Comment: use: extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Da uma conferida no seu arquivo **build.gradle** dentro do diretório **app**, ve se tem essas infos nas dependências:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
```

Mas de qualquer forma, é bom que você poste o erro que está sendo apresentado no LogCat, se não a chance de erros fica muito extensa.

Abraços.

Comment: não deu certo, eu precisaria altera isso

Comment: minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 8

Comment: Me parece que seu targetSdkVersion ta muito baixo, api 8 é o android 2.2, é isso mesmo?